# using pugixml to parse data using C++ but unable to get all the node attributes

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, pugixml

I made a code that parse Function but it won't parse the Argument (name,type) My Code:

```
xml_node GCC_XML = doc.child("GCC_XML");

{


for (xml_node Function = GCC_XML.child("Function");Function; Function= Function.next_sibling("Function"))
{    
    cout<<"Function\n"<<"id= "<<Function.attribute("id").value()<<" , name= "<<Function.attribute("name").value()<<" ,returns: "<<Function.attribute("returns").value()<<Function.child_value("Argument") <<endl;

}

}
```

That is the XML file i am trying to parse

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GCC_XML>
  <Namespace id="_1" name="::" members="_2 _3 _4 "/>
  <Function id="_2" name="main" returns="_5" context="_1" location="f0:8"/>
  <Function id="_3" name="a_function" returns="_5" context="_1" location="f0:4">
    <Argument name="f" type="_6"/>
    <Argument name="e" type="_4"/>
  </Function>
  <Struct id="_4" name="EmptyClass" context="_1" location="f0:1" members="_7 _8 " bases=""/>
  <FundamentalType id="_5" name="int"/>
  <FundamentalType id="_6" name="float"/>
  <Constructor id="_7" name="EmptyClass" context="_4" location="f0:1">
    <Argument name="_ctor_arg" type="_9"/>
  </Constructor>
  <Constructor id="_8" name="EmptyClass" context="_4" location="f0:1"/>
  <ReferenceType id="_9" type="_4c"/>
  <File id="f0" name="example1.cxx"/>
</GCC_XML>
```

The problem is that it refuse to read the functions arguments my results are :

```
 Load result: No error 
Function 
id= _2 , name= main ,returns: _5
 Function 
id= _3 , name= a_function ,returns: _5
```

I also tried

```
cout<<"Function\n"<<"id= "<<Function.attribute("id").value()<<" , name= "<<Function.attribute("name").value()<<" ,returns: "<<Function.attribute("returns").value()<<Function.attribute("Argument") <<endl;
```

put it gave the same result just added 0 output in the Argument output which show it doesn't read it

Put i got the same results above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Argument` is not an *attribute*. It is an *element*, a child element of `Function`. You access child elements the same way you access any element.

`xml_node::child_value` finds the XML element with the given name (`Argument` in this case), and returns the text of the first child text node of that element. `Argument`, in your XML file, is *empty*; it doesn't have child text nodes. It has *attribute* nodes, but that's not the same thing. If you want the attributes of `Argument`, you have to ask for them, exactly as you asked for the attributes of the `Function` node.

Comment: xml_node GCC_XML = doc.child("GCC_XML");

{


for (xml_node Argument = GCC_XML.child("Argument");Argument; Argument= Argument.next_sibling("Argument"))
{    
    cout<<"Argument\n"<<"Name= "<<Argument.attribute("name").value()<<" , Type= "<<Argument.attribute("Argument").value() <<endl;

}

}

Comment: @MicHans: OK, so... what does that mean?

Comment: I am asking if that's what you meant to call for the Argument node attributes (name,Type)? Am newbie to programming generally

Comment: @Mic: Please stop posting code in comments. Why don't you try the code yourself, see if it works, and then ask about it in your *question* if it doesn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas your clear explaination of this helped me pass a failing test.